# rt3070 won't connect to WiFi

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

So I'm purchasing various WiFi adapters for the sole purpose of using Wireshark and other pentesting tools. My first two purchases were TP Link 722n with the chipset ar9271/ath9k driver(works great) and the 727n chipset rt5370/rt2800usb driver(works great). My third WiFi adapter is a generic brand rt3070/rt2800usb driver. The reasoning behind the different chipset versions is to identify which chipsets work best in certain situations. Now my problem is that the third WiFi adapter rt3070/rt2800usb won't connect to WiFi(wlan3,4,ect..). My concern is if I make any modifications will that limit my use of other chipset versions, is the rt3070 a usable chipset version. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A rookie mistake. I forgot to whitelist the MAC address associated with the new WiFi adapter. Once the MAC address was whitelisted the adapter worked fine.